# Javascript increments of 0.005

Tags: javascript

I am implementing a business rule that says "**a number must be in increments of 0.005 to be valid**"

These are good:

```
123.005
123.0
```

These are bad:

```
123.004
123.1001
```

I've tried the modulus operator, but get unexpected numbers:

```
var x = 5.005;
var z = x % .005;
```

The result is 0.004999999999999789

**Note: This question is NOT about rounding, it is about finding values that are increments of 0.05**

Here's the solution:

```
//Multiply by 200 to get  a full int value (.005 * 200 ==  1)
if ((limitPrice * 200) % 1 !== 0) { 
     isFailure = true;
      errorMsg = "Blah blah";
}
```

Comment: Would rounding `123.004` then adding `0.005` help?

Comment: I would work with integers and then move the decimal point when displaying it

Comment: You can try this - `var x = 5.005;` `var z = (x * 1000) % 5;`

Comment: Victor - Your answer was correct.